# Help with Calculus Integral application.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $S$ be the solid whose base is the region in the $x,y$-plane bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=1$ whose cross-sections parallel to the $y$-axis are equilateral triangles. Find the volume of $S$.

My work so far:

We know that the area of an equilateral triangle is $\frac{s^2\sqrt3}{4}.$ Since the cross-section are equilateral triangles and parallel to the y-axis, we also know that the side of the equilateral triangle is $1 - x^2,$ giving us $\frac{\sqrt3}{4}(1 - x^2)^2.$ Now, we use the formula $\int_a^{b} A(x) \, dx$ to find the volume. We get $\int_a^{b} \frac{\sqrt3}{4}(1 - x^2)^2 \, dx.$ That's what I have done so far, how do I find the limits of integration? Thanks

Comment: when curves that bound the base ($y=1, y=x^2$) intersect?

Comment: But that would just be 1 and -1?

Comment: There are your limits of integration.

Comment: Can you please explain to me, thanks for your help!